# Time complexity and space complexity in recursive algorithm

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, space-complexity

```
"The designer of an algorithm needs to balance between space complexity and time
complexity." - Comment on the validity of the statement in the context of recursive
algorithms.
```

This is a question from my university's previous paper. But i couldn't find a decent answer. Actually i am confused about how can a developer minimize the time-complexity for any recursive function. I get that if there is a **tail-recursion** then space complexity can be minimized. But can't get the idea of time-complexity.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand the question. The [space-time tradeoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space%E2%80%93time_tradeoff) is about decreasing space or time at the cost of the other (**"balance between"** points to this being what the question is talking about). So I don't think tail-recursion classifies - I believe it decreases both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing comes in mind is [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Simple well studied problem for this is Fibonacci numbers, simple recursion is as follow:

```
fib(int n)
{
  if (n < 3)
    return 1;

  return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

But with memoization, we can use an auxiliary array to get rid of extra calls:

```
f[1]=f[2] = 1;
fib(int n)
{
  if (n < 3)
    return 1;

  if (f[n] == 0)
     f[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);

  return f[n];
}
```

This simple change, reduces the time from $\Theta(\phi^n)$ to $\Theta(n)$.

The memoization technique sometimes uses more memory, but very faster in time, and one of a tradeoffs that software developer should be care about it is this.

**Explanation of the memoization of Fibonacci numbers:**

First we create an array $f$, to save the values that already computed. This is the main part of all memoization algorithms. Instead of many repeated recursive calls we can save the results, already obtained by previous steps of algorithm. As shown in the algorithm we set the $f[1],f[2]$ to $1$.

In the first `if` we actually check whether we are in the start or not. But we can remove this `if` statement. But for make it simpler to read I left it.

In the second `if`, we check if the value of `fib(n)` is already computed or not. This prevents us from multiple call for the same number, for example suppose we want to compute `f(6)`, then in normal recursion we have the first recursion tree as shown in the following figure and in the memoization version we have the second tree. The reason is, in memoization we just compute the green vertices one time and then we save them into the memory (array $f$) and if needed we fetch them later.

In the following figure, green nodes are parts which are necessary to be computed (in this way), yellow nodes are precomputed ones, and red nodes are the nodes that are repeatedly computed in the first recursion.

As is clear from the image, in the normal case we have just precomputed `f(1)` and `f(2)`, but in the memoization case, all functions for less than $n-1$ are precomputed, and this causes exponentially smaller recursion tree. (In memoization number of red nodes is zero, which is exponential in the normal recursion).

[image: First tree is normal recursion tree, second one is by memoization.]

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. The recursive solution requires the stack to be stored, which likely uses more memory than the memoization's array.

Comment: @Dukeling, If you see my answer, I didn't say that in this case, I said *sometimes*. On the other hand you are right, memoization is very good even in memory, in most times. But I mentioned this to notify OP about the usage of this technique to reduce the time complexity (not memory).

Comment: Ok, the memoization code you provided does actually seem to use slightly more memory. But IMO it's a non-issue, since you can just use a simple for-loop to populate the array, which is faster and uses less memory than either. And this can further be optimized (assuming you only do a single call) to only store the last 2 values, thus constant space.

Comment: But a for-loop wouldn't be recursive any more, so I suppose this answer answers the question - I'm just not too fond of giving examples of things that can easily be done a lot better, even though Fibonacci numbers is a popular example for recursive functions.

Comment: @Dukeling, Everything which is written recursively can be written by stack and for loop, and nearly all memoization stuffs can be written by multiple for loops. But the reason that we use memoization instead of normal dynamic programming is because the formulation of problem is easier. Also compiler will optimize the recursion, so we do not need to write dirty for loops. Also usually memoization used for more than one dimention recursion, or if we have multiple relative function not in Fibonacci, in that cases memoization causes to clean code.

Comment: @Dukeling, I didn't provide more complex example (that I have some of them in hand), to make it easy to understand. Otherwise someone should understand what is the problem, why this is correct and so on. Also in this case, memoization just uses one extra array and just one time recursion of depth $n$, but the full recursion version depends to the compiler, and in my opinion first one needs slightly more memory (for allocations and keeping temporary memories) in most cases (except possibly the first call).

Comment: Yes, recursion is really only there to make things easier for the programmer, but in this case a simple for-loop isn't really more difficult (I'm inclined to say it's easier, than the memoization at least) - `int arr[n]; arr[0] = arr[1] = 1; for (i = 2:n) arr[i] = arr[i-1] + arr[i-2]; return arr[n-1];`. But yes, as I said - "I suppose this answer answers the question".

Comment: @Dukeling, I see your point, but I mentioned why I provided Fibonacci numbers as sample, and this is the reason many people around the world are using Fibonacci numbers for recursion. Just because is simple to understand the idea.

Comment: @Saeed i'm not getting how will
    `if (f[n-1] == 0)
         f[n-1] = fib(n-1);`
work?

Comment: @tintinmj, I supposed that the array value is set to zero in the creation time, After that, if we call fib(n-1), this will call all other previous values recursively, and then will fill them bottom up, instead of working top-down, we changed the algorithm to work with it bottom up. The reason that this work is, array **f** holds precomputed values, and we do not need to recompute everything many time. We compute everything one time and then we fetch them from the memory. I changed the algorithm to be more clear and more similar to the normal recursive one.

Comment: If you have problem to see why this is $\Theta(n)$, let me know, I'll explain it in detail.

Comment: @SaeedAmiri yes actually i'm having difficulty understanding the code.I will be very glad if you can please explain with proper code and comments.

Comment: @tintinmj, I updated the answer, take a look at it. And if there is any question let me know.

Comment: Also read the code again.

Comment: Good to see this.